# How to read and interpret Packet Formats in RFCs (Request For Comments)?

Tags: documentation, packet, protocol, network-protocols

Often times when I am reading Request For Comments documentation, I always see the packet format section for a protocol outlined like the one below. My question is what do the numbers and different symbols (+-|) represent?

```
  A summary of the RADIUS data format is shown below.  The fields are
   transmitted from left to right.

     0                   1                   2                   3
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |     Code      |  Identifier   |            Length             |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |                                                               |
    |                         Authenticator                         |
    |                                                               |
    |                                                               |
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
    |  Attributes ...
    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers are bit numbers, starting with the most significant bit. It may seem counter-intuitive that bit `0` is the most significant bit, but it is the first bit transmitted. The Network Byte (and bit) Order is big-endian (most significant first).

The other symbols are to show the individual bits, a kind of incomplete grid.

There are RFCs that explain this. For example, [*RFC 1700, ASSIGNED NUMBERS*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700):

> Data Notations
>
> The convention in the documentation of Internet Protocols is to
> express numbers in decimal and to picture data in "big-endian" order
> [[COHEN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700#ref-COHEN)].  That is, fields are described left to right, with the
> most significant octet on the left and the least significant octet on
> the right.
>
> The order of transmission of the header and data described in this
> document is resolved to the octet level.  Whenever a diagram shows a
> group of octets, the order of transmission of those octets is the
> normal order in which they are read in English.  For example, in the
> following diagram the octets are transmitted in the order they are
> numbered.
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       1       |       2       |       3       |       4       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       5       |       6       |       7       |       8       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |       9       |      10       |      11       |      12       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> Transmission Order of Bytes
>
> Whenever an octet represents a numeric quantity the left most bit in
> the diagram is the high order or most significant bit.  That is, the
> bit labeled 0 is the most significant bit.  For example, the following
> diagram represents the value 170 (decimal).
>
> ```
>                       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>                      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>                      |1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0|
>                      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> Significance of Bits
>
> Similarly, whenever a multi-octet field represents a numeric quantity
> the left most bit of the whole field is the most significant bit.
> When a multi-octet quantity is transmitted the most significant octet
> is transmitted first.

Comment: is there a reason why the bit "groups" are numbered on 10b boundaries, instead, on the more natural octet boundaries ? (IOW, why 0-9 0 -9 ... instead of 0-7 0-7 ...)